# What can the USA do if the current regime in Bangladesh holds a 'staged' election for the third time?

Tags: united-states, bangladesh

Sensing an imminent vote rigging in the coming election in January 2024, on May 24th, 2023, the USA announced a new visa policy for Bangladesh.

- [Announcement of Visa Policy to Promote Democratic Elections in Bangladesh](https://www.state.gov/announcement-of-visa-policy-to-promote-democratic-elections-in-bangladesh/)

Analysts are saying that the ruling government is preparing for another rigged election without paying heed to the Western pressure.

- [Washington Can Give Bangladesh’s Democracy the Kiss of Life](https://foreignpolicy.com/2023/08/03/washington-bangladesh-democracy-elections-hasina/?tpcc=recirc_latest062921)
- [Awami League thinking of elections without BNP](https://en.prothomalo.com/bangladesh/politics/rg5jsxti31)
- [PM Hasina seeks vote for ‘Boat' for another term](https://en.prothomalo.com/bangladesh/politics/cmycqk0x8w)

Allegedly, Russia and China are preparing to back this government -

- [Russia's Sberbank exploring providing banking services in Bangladesh](https://www.reuters.com/article/russia-banks-bangladesh/russias-sberbank-exploring-providing-banking-services-in-bangladesh-idUSL8N3962SG)
- [Is Bangladesh edging closer to China and Russia?](https://www.dw.com/en/is-bangladesh-edging-closer-to-china-and-russia/a-65921709)
- [Chinese Foreign Ministry Spokesperson Wang Wenbin's Remarks on Foreign Country’s Sanctions on Bangladesh](http://bd.china-embassy.gov.cn/eng/sghd/202306/t20230614_11096467.htm)

My question is, suppose, the ruling regime holds another rigged election (for which the preparation is well underway) and set the stage to rule the country for another five years, what can the USA do to stop this government from continuing the regime?

Comment: Why do you suppose it is the job for the USA?  These questions are phrased in a fairly tiresome way.  You spend more time telling us about how much you dislike the regime than actually asking the question. Then the question, when asked seems, strangely, to assume that the USA should choose the government of Bangladesh. Perhaps you could cut the regime bashing, and consider what your question really is.

Comment: @JamesK, My real question is what I wrote. Given the frequency of US officials visiting BD's ministries and other offices, the USA seems to be very much worried about the current regime staying for another term. Part of the reason is this PM has very good relations with the Chinese and Russians. Indians brought her into power, but Americans now blocked Indians from meddling in because the PM has now become a gangrene.

Comment: But suppose I turned this around and said "The US seems to be planning a rigged election, after the last rigged election" (and a large minority of Americans do believe this) "So what can Bangladesh do to prevent Biden from becoming President again?"  -- I'm pretty sure such a question would be rapidly downvoted!  Why should it be Bangladesh who gets to choose the President of the USA?  Why Should the USA get to choose the Prime Minister of Bangladesh?

Comment: @JamesK, *Why Should the USA get to choose the Prime Minister of Bangladesh?* --- This is a fallacious question. The USA doesn't want to choose BD's PM, rather wants to contain the Chinese and Russian influence on Bangladesh. A third *staged* election will allow China and Russia to take control of Bangladesh forever because Bangladesh will virtually become a one-party state.

Comment: Yes... okay, So is your question "How can the US government contain the influence of Russia and China on the Government of Bangladesh?"  - So perhaps I could ask "How can the Government of China contain the influence of the US and Russia  on Bangladesh?"  But anyway, the answer is as usual "It can wave a carrot, or it can wave a big stick, but short of invasion there is little it can do to force anything"

Comment: I invite you to make a new title, since this one is pretty hard to tell what the quesiton is about.

Answer (score 7):

> what can the USA do to stop this government from continuing the
> regime?

Nothing.

As a practical matter the USA can express its strong objections and reduce diplomatic cooperation, but it has no power to bring about regime change in Bangladesh, or at least, no interest in devoting the resources that would be necessary to do so.

Comment: *no interest in devoting the resources that would be necessary to do so.* -- Then, you are not following Bangladesh's affairs. You are not following the activities of the EU and the US diplomats and the frequency of holding meetings in Bangladesh.

Comment: @user366312 the US directly changed the regime in Iraq and Afganistan (for a time) this century

Comment: @Caleth, Yeah, but those days are over. You recently saw how the PM of Pakistan was making so much noise when he was ousted by the USA. Also, the USA is bogged down in the Ukraine war.

Comment: @Caleth Bangladesh is not Iraq or Afghanistan. During the Bangladesh liberation wars, the indians who trained the Bangladesh refugees noted that most of the Bengali refugees who volunteered were well educated and fast learners. They performed exceptionally well in the field providing the liberation army with precise intelligence and were also very successful in many sabotage missions that crippled the enemy. Moreover, the US will need the support of India to invade Bangladesh, and it is highly unlikely that India will support them.

Comment: @user366312 U.S. national policy makers simply don't care one way or the other about Bangladesh and are barely aware that it exists. Iraq had oil and the U.S. had already fought one war with it over its invasion of Kuwait. Afghanistan drew interest from U.S. leaders because of 9-11. Also, it would take immense resources (far more than the Iraq War or the "War on Terrorism") to force regime change in Bangladesh in a place where U.S. military bases/resources are scarce.